# Chainmenu items need to add more select menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make chainmenu items. It works fine with two select menu but if I increase the number of select menus it doesn't work.

Any help much appreciated.
Many thanks in advance.

```
<label>Index</label>
      <select class="selectDrop" name="firstlevel" style="width:180px;" lang="de">
      </select>
      <label>Categories</label>
      <select class="selectDrop" name="secondlevel" id="dtPopulate" style="width:180px;">
      </select>     
      <input type="button" class="submit-button" value="Submit" onClick="goListGroup(document.getElementsByName('firstlevel')[0], document.getElementsByName('secondlevel')[0])">
      <div id="rimContent"></div>
```

here is the jsfiddle URL:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/mufeedahmad/6nAE6/13/